# GWT plugin doesn't work in Chrome 46

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

My project is using GWT. I have installed GWT plugin for Chrome Browser and I see it is in the added extensions and enabled. I am using the newest version of chrome which is 46 .When run the project, Chrome browser always announce

Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plugin

I have attached the image bellow
[image]

Please help me how to fix this to run it in development mode. Thank you.

Comment: The GWT plugin stops working with since version 35 or so. You have to use Super Dev Mode.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please tell me if you any idea how to integrate Jquery library function in gwt? I mean how to call it on a html div into it.

Comment: You should post it as a separate question.